# Pegar Objeto em JSON

Tags: javascript, ajax, json

Como posso fazer para pegar só a propriedade **`"name":"josimara"`** nesse código `ajax`, sou novata nessa área, agradeço por a ajuda.

```
<script src="http://www.habbid.com.br/assets/js/jquery-1.9.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

var yql_url = 'https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql';

var url = 'https://www.habbo.com.br/api/public/users?name=josimara';

$.ajax({
  'url': yql_url,
  'data': {
    'q': 'SELECT * FROM json WHERE url="'+url+'"',
    'format': 'json',
    'jsonCompat': 'new',
  },
  'dataType': 'jsonp',
  'success': function(response) {
    console.log(response);
    document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = JSON.stringify(response);
  },
  'error': function(error) {
    document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = "error";
  }
});
</script>

<span id='test'>nothing</span>
```

Comment: você quer pegar a informação da `var url`?

Comment: O nosso amigo **Sergio** já deu a solução

Comment: Isso @rLinhares

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O que procuras é

```
 document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = response.query.results.json.name;
```

Se olhares o JSON que a API retorna, são essas as propriedades que tens de percorrer.

Exemplo:

```js
var yql_url = 'https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql';
var url = 'https://www.habbo.com.br/api/public/users?name=josimara';

$.ajax({
  'url': yql_url,
  'data': {
    'q': 'SELECT * FROM json WHERE url="' + url + '"',
    'format': 'json',
    'jsonCompat': 'new',
  },
  'dataType': 'jsonp',
  'success': function(response) {
    console.log(response);
    document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = response.query.results.json.name;
  },
  'error': function(error) {
    document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = "error";
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://www.habbid.com.br/assets/js/jquery-1.9.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>



<span id='test'>nothing</span>
```

Comment: Olá @Sergio uma duvida porque que com esse JSON esta dando valor indefinido http://shipdesk.in/mobile/mobile_quick.php?country=IN&to_country=IN&pin=560001&weight=2.5&unit=KG&need_cod=No&to_pin=700001 Desejo pegar o "Service"

Comment: @Josimara esse json tem uma array dentro. Aí tens de ir por chave numérica.

Comment: poderia dar uma solução para nos? Thanks

Comment: @Josimara sim, mas não sei o que queres tirar desse json, é diferente da pergunta. Qual é a chave que queres, e queres só um deles, ou alguns?

Comment: queria tirar a chave "Service":"Delhivery_Surface"

Comment: @Josimara todas ou só uma?

Comment: Pegando o valor desse json objeto Url já mata a charada `{"content": {"url": "meusite.com.br","valor": "4.50"}}`

Comment: @Josimara não percebi o ultimo comentário. Isso é outro json? esse é idêntico ao da pergunta, ou seja sem array.

Comment: Vou montar ele certinho para você ver o resultado final, um momento.

Comment: Pronto @Sergio {"query":{"count":1,"created":"2017-10-03T18:37:07Z","lang":"pt-BR","results":{"content":{"url":"meusite.com.br","valor":"4.50"}}}} precisaria pegar a url, é outro json

Comment: @Josimara `var resultado = response.query.results.content;`

Comment: no caso ficaria document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = response.query.results.json.content.url; ?

Comment: @Josimara não sei a que JSON te referes, mas o que referiste [neste comentário](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/242938/pegar-objeto-em-json/242942?noredirect=1#comment497695_242942) ficaria: `document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = response.query.results.content.url;`

Comment: Resolvido, Abraço!